# Field equations of 11d supergravity in geometrical notation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, supergravity

In [1112.4967](https://arxiv.org/abs/1112.4967), it is stated that the field equations of 11d supergravity are (eq. 24 there) $$\operatorname{Ric}(X,Y)=\frac{1}{2}\langle\imath_XF,\imath_YF\rangle-\frac
{1}{6}g(X,Y)\langle F,F\rangle$$ (plus a Maxwell equation), where $F$ is a 4-form and $g$ the metric, and the inner product is given by $$\langle\alpha,\beta\rangle\star 1=\alpha\wedge\star\beta.$$ I am trying to check that the geometrical notation above recovers the more common field equation (see e.g. [hep-th/9912164](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9912164)) $$\underbrace{G_{MN}}_{\text{Term I}}=\underbrace{\frac{1}{12}F_{MPQR}F_N^{\ PQR}}_{\text{II}}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{96}g_{MN}F_{PQRS}F^{PQRS}}_{\text{III}}\tag{1}$$ where $G$ is the Einstein tensor. Indeed, I can show that $\langle\imath_XF,\imath_YF\rangle=(1/3!)X^MY^NF_M^{\ PQR}F_{NPQR}$ and $\langle F_4,F_4\rangle=(1/4!)F_{MNPQ}F^{MNPQ}$, so that I recover successfully term II in eq (1). I also recover term III, albeit with the coefficient $1/144$ rather than $1/96$. Instead of the Einstein tensor (term I), however, I clearly only have the Ricci tensor.

Where have I gone wrong? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you got the factors right. You only need to get $R_{MN}$ on the LHS. Use (1) to calculate
$$R_{MN}g^{MN}-\frac{1}{2}g_{MN}g^{MN}R = \frac{1}{12}F_{MPQR}F_{N}^{~~PQR}g^{MN}-\frac{1}{96}g_{MN}g^{MN}|F|^2$$
where I used the short-hand notation $F_{PQRS}F^{PQRS}=|F|^2$.

Actually, your eq. (1) seems to have a sign error, see eq. (2.1) in the lectures by Duff.

Notice that
$$g_{MN}g^{MN}=D=11$$

In this way I obtain
$$R = \frac{1}{144}|F|^2$$

Now, you can substitute this result into your equation (1) and solve for $R_{MN}$. I obtain:
$$R_{MN}=\frac{1}{12}F_{MPQR}F_{N}^{~~RQR}-\frac{1}{144}g_{MN}|F|^2 \ ,$$
as desired.